# Facebook Pixel and Safari IOS - "Object.values is not a function."

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, opencart, pixel

Guys i have some trouble with facebook pixel.
It's some strange cosmetic error and it doesn’t affect anything except personal irritation.

All js error on my site logged to my DB and there more than 500 errors every day =(

Maybe someone came across this and knows how to fix it, except "how to disable the log for this")?

Browser stack error
[image]

In MySql error log =(
[image]

Thx.

p.s. Testing on another sites that have pixel - error to.

p.s.2 Site on Opencart

p.s. 3 My pixel code

```html
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', '{i_hide_it}');
            fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={i_hide_it}&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

Comment: _“Testing on another sites that have pixel - error to.”_ - then I’d report a bug to Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs